# How to compile '97 C codes using Motif?

Tags: c, linux, unix, xlib, motif

Hi I'm trying to compile about 30 C sources written in 1997.
Based on required header files such as XmAll.h and Xlib.h and the use of "Widget" syntax, I found that these sources depend on the Motif programming tool kits, so it seems they should be compiled in Linux or Unix system.

I have no any experience with X Windows Programming and Motif programing, but I must compile them.
I really tried to compile them in Mac OSX or Windows, but of course it didn't work.

Do I have to install Linux as virtual OS first and install Open Motif in it to compile them?
Could you give any other suggestion?

Thank you so much!

Kyu

Comment: Just to clarify - you need to compile them on Windows or Mac OSX? [your tags don't reflect this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build it on Windows, you could try installing [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) - when you're selecting packages, you'll need all the build tools (like `gcc`, `make`...), X11 (eg. `xorg-server`), and `lesstif` (Open source Motif clone).

You will probably need to be prepared to massage the source a bit - I doubt it will work "out of the box".

Comment: Thank you! I posted another question with detail information.